# Delete rows containing value from another sheet in Google Sheets using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two spreadsheets named 'Database' and 'Form'.

I'd like to delete rows in 'Database' sheet if their 'Date' column contains matching value with cell 'C2' of 'Form' sheet using Apps Script. Here's what I have :

```js
function submitFormData() {

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  const ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  const form = sheet.getSheetByName("Form");
  
  const database = sheet.getSheetByName("Database");

  const date = form.getRange("C2").getValue(); // Get date value from cell "C2" of 'Form' sheet

  const databaseDates = database.getRange("A2:A").getValues(); // Get all values in 'Date' column of 'Database' sheet

  const blankRow = database.getLastRow()+1;

  const lastRow = database.getLastRow();

  // Loop below checks for and deletes rows that meet the stated condition :

  for ( var i = 2 ; i <= lastRow ; i++){
    if(databaseDates[i] == date){
      database.deleteRow[i];
      }
  }

  // Regardless, paste newly submitted data onto blank rows :

  database.getRange(blankRow,1,3).setValue(form.getRange("C2").getValue());
  database.getRange(blankRow,2,3).setValues(form.getRange("B4:B6").getValues());
  database.getRange(blankRow,3,3).setValues(form.getRange("C4:C6").getValues());

  ui.alert("New Data Saved");

}
```

For whatever reason, the 'for loop' fails to validate any condition so the script simply jumps to execute the setValue() operations below the loop. Here's an illustration of what I'm trying to achieve : [desired sheet result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMrSI.png)

Being a complete newbie in scripting and actually to programming overall, I suspect it's a mistake in writing the Javascript arrays for the 'for loop' etc - but then things got even weirder after I literally copy-pasted this tutorial on a new sheet just to test if it's mainly my poor scripting ability or potentially a bug in the system : https://codewithcurt.com/how-to-clear-delete-insert-and-replace-row-using-google-apps-script/

..and you guessed right, I couldn't even make the deleteRow() function in this tutorial to work.

Other things to note :

1. I've cleared browser cookies, refreshed my sheets, and both browser (Brave) and OS (MacOS) are up-to-date
2. The data format in cell "C2" of 'Form' sheet and that in 'Date' column of 'Database' sheet is the same (Date format)

Lastly, link to a dummy sheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U4RaP7TG5_zfpROQ2ghAG3KKARKjK_YDc7KT02_0F_k/copy

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

The short story is Google Apps Script will sometimes run spreadsheet calls out of order to optimize the work. You can prevent this using [SpreadsheetApp.flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush). Try adding it right under your for loop.

Comment: Tried this and didn't work. I put it in the code just like in this tutorial https://newbedev.com/how-to-refresh-a-sheet-s-cell-value-in-google-apps-script . I wonder if the error of the script not doing its job can be reproduced by everyone else to shed light on what the real issue is (or maybe if there's a mistake with the way the 'for loop' is written can be corrected). Otherwise, thanks for your time.

Comment: I noticed a few things after looking again. The first, and probably your issue is that you are using square brackets on the line that says delete row instead of parentheses.  The second issue you may run into is you are deleting rows as you run into them. This may affect the rows position as you continue down the loop.

Comment: Fixed the main issue (will post an update), now I'm running into the second issue you mentioned. That makes sense as I noticed not all rows got deleted. Might post a separate question if I can't resolve this. Thanks again.